# Drupal + MongoDB + ApacheSolr

Tags: search, database

I'm developing a website which uses MongoDB drupal module, I also need ApacheSolr as search engine, I googled about the Compatibility of ApacheSolr and MondoDB but found nothing.
Can I use Mongo as database and ApacheSolr as search engine (with search api) together?

Comment: Did you try out the above said combination, was it successful?

Answer (score 0):

Given that [Search API](https://drupal.org/project/search_api)/[Search API Solr](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) use Drupal core functions for retrieving entity data in order to be database agnostic, and the [MongoDB module](https://drupal.org/project/mongodb) just adds another database backend for storing items like fields, there wouldn't be a conflict. As long as you stick with Drupal core functions in your custom integration, you should be fine.